# Why isn't my singleton service accessible?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently using Angular 4.4.6 and I've got a number of singleton services in my app, all of which are imported via my `AppModule`> The issue arises with one particular service that requires the inclusion of `providers: [ ViewService ]` importing components' metadata and I'm losing my mind trying to figure out why it's not accessible without the providers declaration like the rest of my services.

To provide a bit of context, here's the offending ViewService's :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Transition } from '@uirouter/angular';

@Injectable()
export class ViewService {
  constructor (
    public http: Http,
    public transition: Transition,
  ) {}

  ... service methods ...

}
```

And my service imports and declarations inside my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { ContactService } from './_services/contact.service';
import { ErrorService } from './_services/error.service';
import { OrganizationService } from './_services/organization.service';
import { ProjectService } from './_services/project.service';
import { TokenService } from './_services/token.service';
import { UserService } from './_services/user.service';
import { ViewService } from './_services/view.service';  <-- offending service

@NgModule({
  imports : [ ... ],
  declarations : [ ... ],
  providers: [
    ContactService,
    ErrorService,
    OrganizationService,
    ProjectService,
    TokenService,
    UserService,
    ViewService,  <-- offending service
  ],
  bootstrap : [ UIView ],
  entryComponents: [ ... ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

And in terms of how the ViewService is imported into components, here's one example:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Transition } from '@uirouter/angular';

import { ProjectService } from '../../_services/project.service';
import { ViewService } from '../../_services/view.service';  <-- offending service

@Component({
  selector: 'create-project',
  templateUrl: './create_project.component.html',
  providers: [ ViewService ]   <-- offending service MUST be included in providers, but no other services require this —- but I want it to serve as singleton service, same as the rest of my services.
})

export class CreateProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  ... component variables ...

  constructor (
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public transition: Transition,

    public projectSvc: ProjectService,
    public viewSvc: ViewService,  <-- offending service
  ) {}

  ... component methods ...

}
```

And the error that's returned:

`Error: No provider for t!`

So far as I can tell, there are no differences between my ViewService and my other services in terms of metadata/structure/boilerplate/import method.

Has anyone come across this? Have any ideas for how I might at least debug this further?

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE: here is the full app.module.ts file:

```
// third-party libraries/modules
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { UIRouterModule, UIView } from '@uirouter/angular';
import { DragulaModule } from 'ng2-dragula';

// necessary boot/root elements
import { APP_STATES } from './app.states';
import { routerConfigFn } from './router.config';

// pipes
import { SortAscendPipe } from './_pipes/sort_ascend.pipe';

// custom modules
import { ColumnSortModule } from './sortable_column/sortable_column.module';
import { MultiselectInputModule } from './multiselect_input/multiselect_input.module';

// services
import { AccountContactService } from './_services/account_contact.service';
import { ActivitiesService } from './_services/activities.service';
import { ArchiveService } from './_services/archive.service';
import { ContactService } from './_services/contact.service';
import { DistributionListService } from './_services/distribution_list.service';
import { DragDropService } from './_services/drag_drop.service';
import { ErrorService } from './_services/error.service';
import { NoAuthService } from './_services/no_auth.service';
import { OrganizationService } from './_services/organization.service';
import { ProjectService } from './_services/project.service';
import { SalesforceService } from './_services/salesforce.service';
import { TokenService } from './_services/token.service';
import { UserService } from './_services/user.service';
import { ViewService } from './_services/view.service';

import { InvalidLinkComponent } from './noauth_invalid_link/invalid_link.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './noauth_login/login.component';
import { NoAuthComponent } from './no_auth.component';
import { RedirectCounterComponent } from './noauth_invalid_link/redirect_counter/redirect_counter.component';
import { ResetRequestComponent } from './noauth_reset_request/reset_request.component';
import { SetPasswordComponent } from './noauth_set_password/set_password.component';

// components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ArchiveActionsComponent } from './actions/actions_archive/actions_archive.component';
import { ArchiveImportComponent } from './forms_create/create_contact/archive_import/archive_import.component';
import { ArchiveContactComponent } from './archive_detail/archive_contact/contact.component';
import { ArchiveItemComponent } from './archive_list/archive_item/archive_item.component';
import { ArchiveListComponent } from './archive_list/archive_list.component';
import { ArchiveOrgComponent } from './archive_detail/archive_organization/organization.component';
import { ArchiveProjectComponent } from './archive_detail/archive_project/project.component';
import { ArchiveDivisionComponent } from './archive_detail/archive_division/division.component';
import { AuditTrailComponent } from './audit_trail/audit_trail.component';
import { AuditTrailConfirmAlertComponent } from './modal/alerts/audittrailconfirm_alert/audittrailconfirm_alert.component';
import { AuditTrailConfirmTrigger } from './modal/triggers/audittrailconfirm_alert.modal';
import { CirculateProjectComponent } from './forms_circulate/circulate_project/circulate_project.component';
import { ContactActionsComponent } from './actions/actions_contact/actions_contact.component';
import { CreateContactComponent } from './forms_create/create_contact/create_contact.component';
import { CreateDistListComponent } from './forms_create/create_distlist/create_distlist.component';
import { CreateOrganizationComponent } from './forms_create/create_organization/create_organization.component';
import { CreateOrganizationTrigger } from './modal/triggers/create_organization.modal';
import { CreateProjectComponent } from './forms_create/create_project/create_project.component';
import { CsvImportComponent } from './forms_create/create_contact/csv_import/csv_import.component';
import { CsvImportFailuresAlertComponent } from './modal/alerts/csvimportfail_alert/csvimportfail_alert.component';
import { CsvImportFailuresTrigger } from './modal/triggers/csvimportfail_alert.modal';
import { CurrentProjectsComponent } from './navigation_project/currentprojects/currentprojects.component';
import { CurrentProjectsItemComponent } from './navigation_project/currentprojects/currentprojects_item/currentprojects_item.component';
import { DatabaseImportComponent } from './forms_create/create_contact/db_import/db_import.component';
import { DbImportFailuresAlertComponent } from './modal/alerts/dbimportfail_alert/dbimportfail_alert.component';
import { DbImportFailuresTrigger } from './modal/triggers/dbimportfail_alert.modal';
import { DeletionAlertComponent } from './modal/alerts/deletion_alert/deletion_alert.component';
import { DeletionAlertTrigger } from './modal/triggers/deletion_alert.modal';
import { DistListActionsComponent } from './actions/actions_distlist/actions_distlist.component';
import { DistlistContactComponent } from './distlist_detail/distlist_contact/contact.component';
import { DistlistOrgComponent } from './distlist_detail/distlist_organization/organization.component';
import { DistlistProjectComponent } from './distlist_detail/distlist_project/project.component';
import { DistlistDivisionComponent } from './distlist_detail/distlist_division/division.component';
import { DuplicateEmailAlertComponent } from './modal/alerts/duplicateemail_alert/duplicateemail_alert.component';
import { DuplicateEmailAlertTrigger } from './modal/triggers/duplicateemail_alert.modal';
import { EditContactComponent } from './forms_edit/edit_contact/edit_contact.component';
import { EditDistListComponent } from './forms_edit/edit_distlist/edit_distlist.component';
import { EditOrganizationComponent } from './forms_edit/edit_organization/edit_organization.component';
import { EditOrganizationTrigger } from './modal/triggers/edit_organization.modal';
import { EditProjectComponent } from './forms_edit/edit_project/edit_project.component';
import { ExportArchiveToActiveComponent } from './export_archivetoactive/export_archivetoactive.component';
import { IconsArchive } from './icons/export_archive/export_archive.component';
import { IconsAssistant } from './icons/assistant/assistant.component';
import { IconsBounced } from './icons/bounced/bounced.component';
import { IconsCirculate } from './icons/circulate/circulate.component';
import { IconsContactDigest } from './icons/contact_digest/contact_digest.component';
import { IconsContactPermission } from './icons/contact_permission/contact_permission.component';
import { IconsEditContact } from './icons/edit_contact/edit_contact.component';
import { IconsEditOrganization } from './icons/edit_organization/edit_organization.component';
import { IconsEditProject } from './icons/edit_project/edit_project.component';
import { IconsExportDoc } from './icons/export_doc/export_doc.component';
import { IconsExportPdf } from './icons/export_pdf/export_pdf.component';
import { IconsInvited } from './icons/invited/invited.component';
import { IconsManageLogos } from './icons/manage_logos/manage_logos.component';
import { IconsNoDocDistribution } from './icons/no_doc_distribution/no_doc_distribution.component';
import { IconsNoneditableBody } from './icons/noneditable_body/noneditable_body.component';
import { IconsNoneditableContact } from './icons/noneditable_contact/noneditable_contact.component';
import { IconsOneOrgImport } from './icons/one_org_import/one_org_import.component';
import { IconsPhoneFormat } from './icons/phone_format/phone_format.component';
import { IconsPrint } from './icons/export_print/export_print.component';
import { IconsProjectOwnership } from './icons/project_ownership/project_ownership.component';
import { IconsReviewPermissions } from './icons/review_permissions/review_permissions.component';
import { IconsSetPassword } from './icons/set_password/set_password.component';
import { IconsToEditContact } from './icons/toedit_contact/toedit_contact.component';
import { IconsToEditOrganization } from './icons/toedit_organization/toedit_organization.component';
import { IconsToEditProject } from './icons/toedit_project/toedit_project.component';
import { InvalidProjectAlertComponent } from './modal/alerts/invalid_project/invalid_project.component';
import { InvalidProjectAlertTrigger } from './modal/triggers/invalid_project.modal';
import { LogoManagementComponent } from './logo_management/logo_management.component';
import { ManualCreateComponent } from './forms_create/create_contact/manual/manual.component';
import { NestedContactComponent } from './nested_detail/nested_contact/contact.component';
import { NestedOrganizationComponent } from './nested_detail/nested_organization/organization.component';
import { NestedProjectComponent } from './nested_detail/nested_project/project.component';
import { NestedDivisionComponent } from './nested_detail/nested_division/division.component';
import { NotAllowedComponent } from './not_allowed/not_allowed.component';
import { PreArchiveComponent } from './forms_create/create_archive/create_archive.component';
import { PrintHtmlBaseTemplateComponent } from './templates/print_html/template_base.component';
import { ProjectActionsComponent } from './navigation_project/projectactions/projectactions.component';
import { ProjectNavigationComponent } from './navigation_project/navigation_project.component';
import { RelationshipSearchComponent } from './relationship_search/relationship_search.component';
import { RelationshipViewComponent } from './relationship_view/relationship_view.component';
import { SalesforceImportComponent } from './forms_create/create_contact/salesforce_import/salesforce_import.component';
import { SalesforceImportConfirmAlertComponent } from './modal/alerts/salesforce_import_confirm/salesforce_import_confirm.component';
import { SalesforceImportConfirmTrigger } from './modal/triggers/salesforce_import_confirm.modal';
import { SiteBannerComponent } from './navigation_site/site_banner/site_banner.component';
import { SiteNavigationComponent } from './navigation_site/navigation_site.component';
import { UserLogoComponent } from './navigation_site/userlogo/userlogo.component';
import { UserSettingsComponent } from './settings_user/settings_user.component';
import { VcardImportComponent } from './forms_create/create_contact/vcard_import/vcard_import.component';
import { ViewErrorsComponent } from './view_errors/view_errors.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';
import { WrongStatusAlertComponent } from './modal/alerts/wrong_status/wrong_status.component';
import { WrongStatusAlertTrigger } from './modal/triggers/wrong_status.modal';

@NgModule({
  imports : [ // third party libraries/modules go here
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    BrowserModule,
    UIRouterModule.forRoot({
      states: APP_STATES,
      useHash: true,
      otherwise: { state: 'invalidLink' },
      config: routerConfigFn,
    }),
    DragulaModule,

    ColumnSortModule,
    MultiselectInputModule,
  ],
  declarations : [ // all custom components go here
    // pipes
    SortAscendPipe,

    InvalidLinkComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NoAuthComponent,
    RedirectCounterComponent,
    ResetRequestComponent,
    SetPasswordComponent,

    // components
    AppComponent,
    ArchiveActionsComponent,
    ArchiveImportComponent,
    ArchiveContactComponent,
    ArchiveItemComponent,
    ArchiveListComponent,
    ArchiveOrgComponent,
    ArchiveProjectComponent,
    ArchiveDivisionComponent,
    AuditTrailComponent,
    AuditTrailConfirmAlertComponent,
    AuditTrailConfirmTrigger,
    CirculateProjectComponent,
    ContactActionsComponent,
    CreateContactComponent,
    CreateDistListComponent,
    CreateOrganizationTrigger,
    CreateOrganizationComponent,
    CreateProjectComponent,
    CsvImportComponent,
    CsvImportFailuresAlertComponent,
    CsvImportFailuresTrigger,
    CurrentProjectsComponent,
    CurrentProjectsItemComponent,
    DatabaseImportComponent,
    DbImportFailuresAlertComponent,
    DbImportFailuresTrigger,
    DeletionAlertComponent,
    DeletionAlertTrigger,
    DistListActionsComponent,
    DistlistContactComponent,
    DistlistOrgComponent,
    DistlistProjectComponent,
    DistlistDivisionComponent,
    DuplicateEmailAlertComponent,
    DuplicateEmailAlertTrigger,
    EditContactComponent,
    EditDistListComponent,
    EditOrganizationComponent,
    EditOrganizationTrigger,
    EditProjectComponent,
    ExportArchiveToActiveComponent,
    IconsArchive,
    IconsAssistant,
    IconsBounced,
    IconsCirculate,
    IconsContactDigest,
    IconsContactPermission,
    IconsEditContact,
    IconsEditOrganization,
    IconsEditProject,
    IconsExportDoc,
    IconsExportPdf,
    IconsInvited,
    IconsManageLogos,
    IconsNoDocDistribution,
    IconsNoneditableBody,
    IconsNoneditableContact,
    IconsOneOrgImport,
    IconsPhoneFormat,
    IconsPrint,
    IconsProjectOwnership,
    IconsReviewPermissions,
    IconsSetPassword,
    IconsToEditContact,
    IconsToEditOrganization,
    IconsToEditProject,
    InvalidProjectAlertComponent,
    InvalidProjectAlertTrigger,
    LogoManagementComponent,
    ManualCreateComponent,
    NestedContactComponent,
    NestedOrganizationComponent,
    NestedProjectComponent,
    NestedDivisionComponent,
    NotAllowedComponent,
    PreArchiveComponent,
    PrintHtmlBaseTemplateComponent,
    ProjectActionsComponent,
    ProjectNavigationComponent,
    RelationshipSearchComponent,
    RelationshipViewComponent,
    SalesforceImportComponent,
    SalesforceImportConfirmAlertComponent,
    SalesforceImportConfirmTrigger,
    SiteBannerComponent,
    SiteNavigationComponent,
    UserLogoComponent,
    UserSettingsComponent,
    VcardImportComponent,
    ViewErrorsComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    WrongStatusAlertComponent,
    WrongStatusAlertTrigger,
  ],
  providers: [ // services go here
    AccountContactService,
    ActivitiesService,
    ArchiveService,
    ContactService,
    DistributionListService,
    DragDropService,
    ErrorService,
    NoAuthService,
    OrganizationService,
    ProjectService,
    SalesforceService,
    TokenService,
    UserService,
    ViewService
  ],
  bootstrap : [ // root component goes here
    UIView
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    CreateOrganizationTrigger,
    CreateOrganizationComponent,
    EditOrganizationTrigger,
    EditOrganizationComponent,
    DeletionAlertTrigger,
    DeletionAlertComponent,
    CsvImportFailuresAlertComponent,
    CsvImportFailuresTrigger,
    DbImportFailuresAlertComponent,
    DbImportFailuresTrigger,
    AuditTrailConfirmAlertComponent,
    AuditTrailConfirmTrigger,
    DuplicateEmailAlertComponent,
    DuplicateEmailAlertTrigger,
    InvalidProjectAlertComponent,
    InvalidProjectAlertTrigger,
    WrongStatusAlertComponent,
    WrongStatusAlertTrigger,
    SalesforceImportConfirmAlertComponent,
    SalesforceImportConfirmTrigger
  ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: where does this component belongs to

Comment: Both the component and all my services are imported via the AppModule.

Comment: Try to remove that service and check weather same error comes for others also

Comment: I once spent a day debugging something that turned out to be an extra misplaced comma.  So, just to be sure remove that trailing comma and see what happens.  Alternatively, look for any place you   may have double commas such as in declarations or imports.

Comment: Have you tried importing on the Component you want to use it ? 
Example:

@Component({
   selector: 'app-child',
   providers: [ ViewService ]
})
export class ChildComponent {. . .}

Comment: @KShewengger I can get it working IF I import via the providers array. I already know this and am attempting to avoid it.

Comment: @MukulSharma the ViewService is DEEPLY integrated and would take a LONG while to remove from all components that call it. It is the last service I added and no other services do/have had this issue.

Comment: full contents of the `app.module.ts` file has been included at the end of the post for reference.

Comment: Are you able to create a stackblitz with this service that can replicate the problem?

Comment: You take backup of ViewSource Content, delete the file and add it again. Might be issue with reference. Not seeing any issue with the code

Comment: Also ViewService is the global class name for AngularJS UI Router. Is it possible to update the Class Name and try out. Ex:  CustomViewService

Comment: I dont understand, if the service is truly singletone and its provided at root module, why do you need to create a new instance of it at component level? (by providing it at component level, a new instance with a lifetime bound to the component will be created)

Answer (score 1):

The `Transition` dependency is not available in root injector. It is only available at component level injector when `uirouter` navigates to that component, that's why it works when you provide `ViewService` at component level.

I don't know why `ViewService` needs `Transition` dependency, but maybe `TransitionService` would fit the need.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer, I naively assumed I could import and generalize my calls to Transition within a Service while it remained a singleton. But that seems very much not to be the case. Thanks for the gentle push in the right direction.

Comment: You still can use `TransitionService` in your `ViewService`, register some hook, e.g. `onEnter` and the callback will receive `Transition`.